# Trying to identify failed component in sewing machine motor

Tags: motor, identification, components

I'm trying to identify a failed component from a domestic sewing machine motor.
The component in question was connected between the incoming neutral wire and everything else (motor+suppression caps), so all motor current ran through it.
It's an axial component, 6.15mm long and 3.5mm dia, marked on the outside with 'T30' in large print followed by '5.L' in smaller print.
Inside the [bakelite?] casing, which split in two when it failed, there's a ~2mm diameter central core of some greyish material with shiny specks in it.
It is possible that it failed because the 3-lead suppression cap failed, burning a hole through its wrapping. That cap has now been replaced with suitable individual X/Y class caps.
Presumably the failed component is some kind of protection device, but if it's just some sort of fuse, being located underneath the board carrying the brushes, it wasn't sited for easy replacement.

Comment: Can you add photos showing the expired device?

Comment: ferrite choke & metal film caps

Comment: Images at:
http://bisun.co.uk/images/resources/sewingmotorpart01.jpg
http://bisun.co.uk/images/resources/sewingmotorpart02.jpg
If it is a ferrite choke, would the numbers on it be any guide as to what to replace it with?